# Tail log file on multiple machines over ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, tail

I'm trying to `tail` a log file on multiple remote machines and forward the output to my local workstation. I want connections to close when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>.

At the moment I have the following function that *almost* works as intended.

```bsh
function dogfight_tail() {
 logfile=/var/log/server.log
 pids=""
 for box in 02 03; do
   ssh server-$box tail -f $logfile | grep $1 &
   pids="$pids $!"
 done
 trap 'kill -9 $pids' SIGINT
 trap  wait
}
```

The connections close and I receive the output from `tail`. BUT, there is some kind of buffering going on because the output come in batches.

And here's the fun part…

I can see the same buffering behaviour when executing the following and append "test" to the file `/var/log/server.log` on the remote machines 4-5 times…

```bsh
ssh server-01 "tail -f /var/log/server.log | grep test"
```

…and found two ways of disabling it…

1. Add -t flag to ssh.

   ```bsh
   ssh -t server-01 "tail -f /var/log/server.log | grep test"
   ```
2. Remove quotation from the remote command.

   ```bsh
   ssh server-01 tail -f /var/log/server.log | grep test
   ```

However, neither of these approaches work for the function that execute on multiple machines mentioned above.

I have tried dsh, which have the same buffering behaviour when executing.

```bsh
dsh -m server-01,server-02 -c "tail -f /var/log/server.log | grep test"
```

Same here, if I remove the quotation, the buffering goes away and everything works fine.

```bsh
dsh -m server-01,server-02 -c tail -f /var/log/server.log | grep test
```

Also tried `parallel-ssh` which works exactly the same as `dsh`. Can somebody explain what's going on here?

How do I fix this problem? Would be ideal to go with straight `ssh` if possible.

P.S. I do not want to use `multitail` or similar since I want to be able to execute arbitrary commands.

Comment: You can checkout [`dbitail`](https://github.com/pschweitz/DBITail/wiki) and download it from [here](https://github.com/pschweitz/DBITail/releases).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

What you see is effect of a standard stdout buffer in `grep` provided by Glibc. The best solution is to disable it by using `--line-buffered` (GNU grep, I'm not sure what other implementations might support it or something similar).

As for **why** this only happens in some cases:

```
ssh server "tail -f /var/log/server.log | grep test"
```

runs the whole command in the quotes on the server - thus `grep` waits to fill its buffer.

```
ssh server tail -f /var/log/server.log | grep test
```

runs `grep` on your local machine on the output `tail` sent through the ssh channel.

The key part here is, that `grep` adjusts its behaviour depending on whether its `stdin` is a terminal or not. When you run `ssh -t`, the remote command is running with a controlling terminal and thus the remote `grep` behaves like your local one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. It make sense to me now and the script works as expected with --line-buffered.

Comment: @deephacks In that case please consider accepting the answer - it gives a clue to others having the same problem.

Comment: grep/glibc's buffering depends on its **stdout**. `ssh tail | grep` outputs to the local terminal, unbuffered. `ssh -t "tail|grep"` outputs to a pty, unbuffered. `ssh "tail|grep"` outputs to a pipe (to `sshd`), buffered (unless `--line-buffered`).

Answer (score 2):

check this out: [`multitail`](https://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/)

MultiTail allows you to monitor logfiles and command output in multiple windows in a terminal, colorize, filter and merge.

To tail logs in multiple servers use:

```
multitail -l 'ssh user@host1 "tail -f /path/to/log/file"' -l 'ssh user@host2 "tail -f /path/to/log/file"'
```

Comment: But it doesn't let you do it over ssh, which is a condition of this question. (And, also, the question specifically says "don't want to use multitail".)

Comment: @bishop: I think this criticism is unfair in part because while the question may have specified not using multitail, it seems to be due to a misunderstanding. The example above shows how to use arbitrary commands and the regular shell expansions also work — `multitail <(ssh …) <(ssh …)` — allowing the desired outcome even if it's not how they originally thought the question could be answered.

Answer (score 1):

You can checkout in'side log.

A Java tool I created, able to read local and distant log files using SSH. It is fairly simple to use.

Some more explanations: https://github.com/pschweitz/insidelog/wiki

Just download version corresponding to your operating system, of native jar release executable within your Java Runtime (requires java 8_40 or higher):

https://github.com/pschweitz/insidelog/releases

You can find a complete documentation (embedded with and in Github's page as well)